# Failed to resolve component in same folder Vue 3

Tags: typescript, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-cli-3, vue-class-components

I am using Vue 3 with class based components and Typescript. If I try to use a component inside another component I get this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: Button
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
```

This `Button` component works without problems in other places.
This is the component where I'm trying to use the `Button` and that throws the error:

```
<template>
    <form>
        <input type="email" />
        <Button text="Submit" />
    </form>
</template>

<script>
import { Vue, Options } from "vue-class-component";
import Button from "@/components/Button";

Options({
  components: {
    Button,
  },
});
export default class Registration extends Vue {}
</script>
```

I use this `Registration` component inside the view `Status` (just another component). This is my folder structure:

```
/src
--/components
----Button.vue
----Registration.vue
--/views
----Status.vue
```

I tried to replicate the same error in another component, and everything works. It looks like the problem is not the location (same folder) of the components.

If I try to console.log the component `Button`, the console will show the component:

```
Object { props: {…}, components: {…}, extends: {}, methods: {}, computed: {}, setup: setup(props, ctx), render: render(_ctx, _cache, $props, $setup, $data, $options), __scopeId: "data-v-015de462", __file: "src/components/Button.vue", __hmrId: "015de462" }
```

But in the template is not rendered. This is what is rendered:

```
<button text="Submit" data-v-5d567869=""></button>
```

I tried to use also other components instead `Button`, but I get the same result.
I tried to import the component with `./Button` instead of `@/components/Button` without success.

EDIT:

As the comment of @jeremy-castelli suggests, I tried to rename the `Button` component in `CustomButton`. I renamed also the filename in `CustomButton.vue`. In template then I used both `<CustomButton ...` and `<custom-button ...`. The error stay the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's beccause it's inside a form, so it considers it like a "normal" html button. It's considered a good practice to not name components with a single word to avoid confusion with html tags

Comment: I tried also with `CustomButton` instead of `Button`. Nothing changes :/

Answer (score 4):

Is embarrassing, but I'll leave the solution here anyway. Let the humiliation serve as a lesson to me.

My decorator `Options({})` is missing the `@`.

It should be `@Options({})`.

:/